# Jquery Expander plugin for FAQ page - Please

Tags: jquery, expander

The FAQ page loads and the answers to the questions show up for a second and then hide.
The page should load without showing the answers at all. It should load showing right away the questions only. 
The script I use is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/jquery.expander.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {          
$('div.readmore').expander({
            slicePoint: 119,
            expandText: 'Read More',
expandSpeed: 'slow',
            userCollapseText: 'Close'
        });
    });
</script>
```

What can I insert to not let this happen anymore? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

in plugin demo page I see they use

`$(document).ready(function() {
...
}`

and you don't

Comment: The OP uses the short version of `$(function () {...})` (http://api.jquery.com/ready/)